# Shlokas from Bhagwata Purana especially for Kaliyuga

Tags: bhagavata-purana, kali-yuga

Just like Bhoomi Gita, what are other chapters in the Bhagwata Purana that explain Kaliyuga?

Only provide me with the chapter numbers or the names.

Comment: Asking for opinions or best and important shlokas is not our scope. Read [ask] and [help/dont-ask] pages.

Comment: This is now a too broad question. Giving list of many chapters and hundreds of shlokas will make a question too broad. Limit it to a specific topic. Please see [help] and [faq].

Comment: Only chapter numbers.

Comment: [This](https://www.vedabase.com/en/search/site/kali?f%5B0%5D=im_vb_book_parent%3A2600) might be helpful..However, it's difficult to list them all so closing as too broad...